# How to add data for new column in Tabulator.js?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a simple table where the main data logic is about columns, not row. The table is about displaying and comparing test results. The test got about 40 different results (=rows). A test is represented by a column. I need to add new test results on the fly.

I have this part working but adding new column `table.addColumn` and updating the whole table data  `table.setData(`

I wonder whether

- there is simple way to add / insert one column data. It is much easier to pass one column data than adding one column to the whole data structure
- some other way how to approach this column based table

working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/u48joxv6/30/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update all the rows in the table at once you can use the `updateData` function, you pass in an array of row objects, each object must contain the [row index field](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/data#row-index) and the field for the column you want to add.

So say for example I had a table with three rows, the index for each column was the `id` field and the new field is `name`:

```js
table.updateData([
    {id:1, name:"steve"},
    {id:2, name:"bob"},
    {id:3, name:"jim"},
]);
```

This would add the data to the rows but would not display it, so we would then need to add the `name` column to the table using the `addColumn` function:

```js
table.addColumn({title:"Name", field:"name"});
```

to display a new column in the table you would nee

Comment: This is what I ended up to do. I thought there there might be a simpler way. Is the order of which I call these two functions important? I call addColumn first and then updateData

Comment: If you add data first then add the column it should be slightly more efficient